# Function with return type based on the generic showing 'not assignable to type' error for returns

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am having trouble when making a recursive generic function that has a return type based on the generic type. When doing this, I am getting a "not assignable to type" error. Despite this, my function is working as intended, so it is simply an issue of the TS error inside the function.

Here is a stripped down example of the issue:

```
type Base = "foo" | "bar"
type Mutate<T extends Base> = T extends "foo" ? "FOO" : T extends "bar" ? "BAR" : never

export const mutate = <T extends Base>(value: T): Mutate<T> => {
    if (value === "foo") {
        return "FOO"
// ---> ~~~~~~
// Type '"FOO"' is not assignable to type 'Mutate<T>'.
    } else {
        return "BAR"
// ---> ~~~~~~
// Type '"BAR"' is not assignable to type 'Mutate<T>'.
    }
}
```

[Code on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigIgGYHstqgH3QCM4AnNAKFEigFkBXYOYCAHgBUoIAPFgOwAmCWIggA%20KKk49%20Q9NlxQA-OgBiAeXV4AXFGm8Ig4WhLll6GAEEASjqh8IANwikKFHmCylgUAMZY%20BB8AW0ZmFCgOLgMjESQxAApHOAAbeghddgBKXQYmFg4JZAkAbwooCqgASwwoJNT0yWRUTBw0LKgyyu6oUghgelI%20NU1KAHoxqABaGYkAPwXFigm9cGgAcjQNLXXq4T4sH0QEKoBzPjgiFOhgLChqDbzwwvWAOnLKgF8uFKROj56vX6g2GaCstmWkxmU3miwWkNWNE24LQuyq%200OUGOZwuVxudweUHWTwK7DEbwBUE%20FE%20QA)

In testing, I have found that directly casting the return value to my desired type instead of declaring it as the return type, it works as expected. Sadly this is not a feasible solution in my case as my real function is recursive and to avoid an `any` return type, recursive functions need a return type annotation otherwise you will get the following error:

> implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions

```
type Base = "foo" | "bar"
type Mutate<T extends Base> = T extends "foo" ? "FOO" : T extends "bar" ? "BAR" : never

export const mutate = <T extends Base>(value: T) => {
    if (value === "foo") {
        return "FOO" as Mutate<T>
    } else {
        return "BAR" as Mutate<T>
    }
}
```

[Code on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigIgGYHstqgH3QCM4AnNAKFEigFkBXYOYCAHgBUoIAPFgOwAmCWIggA+KKk49+Q9NlxQA-OgBiAeXV4AXFGm8Ig4WhLll6GAEEASjqh8IANwikKFHmCylgUAMZY+BB8AW0ZmFCgOLgMjESQxAApHOAAbeghddgBKSQkAbwooIqgASwwoJNT0yWRUTBw0HILilqhSCGB6Uj41TTxEOjCWDjFC4oBfLhSkKGbWovbO7osbfuEGJmH2UZbxinGgA)

Any insight into what is going on here would be greatly appreciated. In the meantime as everything works as intended I am using a `ts-ignore` to hide the error.

Comment: ① I don't understand why you're bringing up return type annotations; you can still use a return type annotation as well as the type assertion.  I mean, if you're willing to use a type assertion, [then you can still do it](https://tsplay.dev/mb1PbN). But that doesn't seem to be what you're asking, is it? The question is... uh, "what's going on here?" Okay.

Comment: ② What's going on is [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), control flow and generic type parameters don't play nicely together, especially with conditional types. I'd refactor to [this generic indexed access version](https://tsplay.dev/mALpXN) but that's out of scope for "what is going on here". ⊛ Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah I am not really looking for a type assertion as given the return type annotation and then function working as expected the type assertion only serves to suppress the ts error, so I don't see this as much better than a ts-ignore. I did however find it very strange that type assertion worked without the return type annotation as my understanding was that those two syntaxes were equivalent.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for linking that issue exactly what I am looking for, there is a draft PR that is actively being worked on that should hopefully sort this out in the longer term. This defiantly answers the "what is going on here" question. As for the refactor, it solves this issue in the example case however for functions that return based on some control flow of the input I can't see how this will work - [example](https://shorturl.at/eQSZ4)

Comment: Okay, can I write an answer to the question as asked and if you have further questions you can ask them separately? Otherwise this ends up being an extended session of follow-ups.

Comment: Yes absolutely, looking forward to reading in full

Comment: BTW, your followup example could be refactored like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDJOzW) using the technique described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my spot:
What if there is a type extends Base, but more. If you set the type as type argument of mutate, then there could be some unexpected case, so "FOO" can not be inferred as Mutate.

type BaseExtend = Base & {
_spec: "foobar"
};

Comment: I have had a little test, and if I am understanding your suggestion correctly I don't think this does the trick. I have put your suggestion in this playground [link](https://shorturl.at/osR79). Is this what you intended? If not could you post a playground link of what you are suggesting (had to use a link shortener to fit in comment character limit)

Comment: Try this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigIgGYHstqgH3QCM4AnNAKFEigFkBXYOYCAHgBUoIAPFgOwAmCWIggA+KKk49+Q9NlxQA-OgBiAeXV4AXFGm8Ig4WhLll6GAEEASjqh8IANwikKFHmCylgUAMZY+BB8AW0ZmFCgACkc4ABt6CF14JABKXQYmFlZk8UkJAG8KKGKoAEsMKJj4lGRUTBw0FKhCktaoUghgelI+NU1KAHoBqABaMYkAPynpiiG9cGgAcjQNLUWy4T4sH0QEUoBzPjgiWOhgLChqJYzwjjFFgDoikoBfLlikZue29s7u3rQVlss2GYxGk2mUxB8xoyyBaHWpU22yguwORxOZwuVygixuWXY9yerReFBeQA)

Comment: I mean when you use generic type with uncertained type argument in a function, the return type of function should be inferred from both your custom type argument and generic type. So if there is a type "BaseExtend", and when you are calling function "mutate" with "BaseExtend" as its type argument, the typeof "FOO" is not be equaled to Mutate<BaseExtend>. That's why you must add "as xxx".

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the function returns a value of type `Mutated<T>` where `T` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, and `Mutated` is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  And TypeScript is currently unable to perform the kind of analysis that can verify if a value of a non-generic type (like `"FOO"` or `"BAR"`) is assignable to such a generic conditional type.  It errs on the side of caution and just rejects it with an error that it is not assignable.

This is a pain point of TypeScript and the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  It's possible that this will eventually be addressed (there is a draft PR at [microsoft/TypeScript#56941](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56941) which might not make it into the language in this form, but at least the TS team is working on it).  But for now, it's not part of the language.

---

Generic type parameters like `T` just don't participate in [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) (like `if`/`else` and `switch`/`case`), and that's the main obstacle here.  Checking `value === "foo"` can narrow the type of `value` from `T` to `T & "foo"`, but it doesn't do anything to `T` itself.  And so since `T` is unchanged and still generic, the type `Mutated<T>` is also unchanged and still generic.  So `"FOO"` isn't known to be of type `Mutated<T>`.

If you want generics to work for you, you should try to refactor your operation so that it doesn't use control flow to distinguish between different output types. For example, since `T` is always a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) in your example, it could be rewritten as a generic [indexing operation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), which can also be *implemented* as indexing:

```
interface Mutated {
    foo: "FOO",
    bar: "BAR"
}

const mutate = <K extends keyof Mutated>(value: K): Mutated[K] => {
    return ({
        foo: "FOO",
        bar: "BAR"
    } as const)[value];
}
```

Obviously the more complicated the example is, the more involved such a refactoring might be.  But usually there is at least some way to do it, even though it ends up performing some hard-to-explain type juggling (see [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)).   But that's out of scope for this question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIFcx0gE2QbwChkTkYB7cgLmQCIAxAeUdoBpjSAjOKG2gIQCCAJVqEAvoUIQAHgAdyUMMgTkQAZ2UBbTNhQBeZAB4A0slmQQOdcgDWEAJ7kYaXbgB8ACgBucADboEDQmAJQ0GFi4ANomALrI+u4EHCRQEGDoUCDInkSk+WSUfEws7AVcPHxCoinI4shwNqoaYCFRvgEQsQDcEkA)